# Date doesnt work - tag value in setFullYear

Tags: javascript

```
var d = new Date();

var gunler= ["Pazar","Pazartesi","Salı","Çarşamba","Perşembe","Cuma","Cumartesi"];
document.getElementById("gun").innerHTML = gunler[d.getDay()];

var ic = document.getElementsByClassName("i");
var dis = document.getElementsByClassName("d");

var ll = document.getElementById("seciligun");
var ll2 = ll.innerHTML;

alert(ll2);
    

d.setFullYear(ll2);


var a=0;
while(a<ic.length){
if(gunler[d.getDay()]=="Cumartesi"||gunler[d.getDay()]=="Pazar"){
    ic[a].innerHTML="";
}
else{
    dis[a].innerHTML="";
}
a=a+1;
}
```

I using these codes in my js file , i taking date in my div tag that id = seciligun. When i use alert it seems like this : 2020-08-15 but when i say alert(d) , browser saying "invalid date". If i write like this d.setFullYear(2020-08-15) everything works correctly but i need use tag's value that id = seciligun.

Comment: The argument to `setFullYear` should just be a year, not a whole date.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the year from `ll2`.

```
var y = ll2.split('-')[0];
d.setFullYear(y);
```

Comment: Thank you , i solved my problem but i little change your code when i tried this everthing worked correctly: var y = ll2.split("-");
y[1]=y[1]-1;
d.setFullYear(y[0],y[1],y[2]);

Comment: I assumed you just wanted to set the year, not the month and day.